# xpath get first element based on multi-level condition

Tags: xpath, conditional-statements, nodes

I have the following xml.

```
<root>
<h>
    <seg>
        <hfield1>hA</hfield1>
        <hfield2>h1</hfield2>
    </seg>
    <seg>
        <hfield1>hB</hfield1>
        <hfield2>h2</hfield2>
    </seg>
</h>
<i>
    <iseg>
        <ifield1>i1</ifield1>
    </iseg>
    <iseg>
        <ifield1>i2</ifield1>
    </iseg>
</i>
<i>
    <iseg>
        <ifield1>i3</ifield1>
    </iseg>
    <iseg>
        <ifield1>i4</ifield1>
    </iseg>
</i>
```

I need to extract the value of hfiel1 if its hfield2 = 'h2' and if at least one ifield1 = 'i2'.
I'm trying xpath 1.0 with this expression. I exptected 'hB' as a result but it's not working.

```
//seg/hfield1/text()[..//hfield2/text() = 'h2' and //ifield1 = 'i2'][1]
```

How can I do?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//seg/hfield1[../hfield2 = 'h2' and //ifield1 = 'i2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to zx485's solution you can also do it with the following XPath 1:0 expression:

```
//seg/hfield2[text() = 'h2' and //ifield1 = 'i2']/preceding-sibling::hfield1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your xml-tree gets bigger I suggest to use a more explicit XPath, i.e:

```
/root[i/iseg/ifield1='i2']/h/seg[hfield2='h2']/hfield1/text()
```